# Scale edge loops along edge

Tags: edges, topology, loop

I have a 6 sided polygon and I'm adding loop cuts to one of the sides not even with either the X or the Y axis. I was wondering, is there a way to scale it along the edge that the loop cut is on?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/slide-two-edge-loops-away-from-each-other/74635#74635

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!