# Make Evenly Spaced Out Loop Cuts

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, loop

I have a trapezoid shape and I want to make loop cuts. but the problem is, is I want the loop cuts not to go across the shapes... "normal"? I guess is what you'd call that. How can I get the lines to be evenly spaced out and the gaps between the lines be parallel no matter what the shape is? (Also, I can't use the knife tool because I need to make a lot of lines).
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/how-to-outset-from-edges-vertices/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/slide-two-edge-loops-away-from-each-other/74635#74635

Comment: I don’t really want to bevel it like that though. Is there not a way to do CRTL- R and the edges just go across the face (not going along it’s normals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knife Project is a possibility.. (Illustrated with X across, Y up)..

- <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>  extrude a long edge horizontally, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> duplicate, <kbd>P</kbd> part off into a new object.
- <kbd>X</kbd> delete the original extrusion, <kbd>X</kbd> delete 'Faces Only' of the new object,  move up in Z, and tweak its X.
- Header Menu > Mesh > Knife Project the grid down onto a couple of your segments:

[image]

Hide the grid...

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>60</kbd>
  the segments, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> repeat,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> > 'By Distance' merge double vertices.

[image]

or, work under a radial Array modifier, if you've got more symmetrical work to do.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!!